# Facebook feature: Help people start a conversation with your Page

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-messenger

The Facebook feature in Settings/Messenger called "Help people start a conversation with your Page" is no longer there, so I can't turn it on or off.  But when people visit my page, the Messenger pop up is asking the wrong questions for my type of business.  How do I either edit the questions or turn off the Chat window pop up?  I don't want to turn Messenger completely off, I'd like potential clients to still be able to Messenger me with actual questions they may have. I'd really appreciate help with this!!  Diane [image]

Comment: I found a way to turn off instant replies, so the Messenger chat box is no longer popping up.  But now it's listing those same questions in a box right on my page.  I've googled automated questions, suggested questions and all kinds of things, but I'm not seeing a solution for it. I hope someone out there has an answer, please!

Answer (score 0):

I found how to turn off the suggested questions!  It's in Inbox -> Automated Responses -> Frequently Asked Questions. You can turn them on or off, and even write your own suggested questions. I turned mine off! Yay!!